# Code giving NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I am new to Python, and I am trying to make a numerical analysis model of differential equations.

```py
import sympy as sympy


def picard_solver(y_0, x_0, rhs_expression, iteration_count:int = 5):
    x, phi = sympy.symbols("x phi")
    
    phi = x_0
    
    for i in range(iteration_count + 1):
        phi = y_0 + sympy.integrate(rhs_expression(x, phi), (x, x_0, x))
        
    return phi
```

```
import numpy 
import plotly.graph_objects as go
    
y_set = [picard_solver(1, 0, lambda x, y: x * y, i)  for i in range(1, 6)]
x_grid = numpy.linspace(-2, 2, 1000)
y_picard = list()

for y in y_set:
    y_picard.append(numpy.array([float(y.evalf(subs={x: x_i})) for x_i in x_grid]))

y_exact = numpy.exp((x_grid) * (x_grid) / 2)
fig = go.Figure()

for i, y_order in enumerate(y_picard):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x_grid, y=y_order, name=f"Picard Order {i + 1}"))

# fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x_grid, y=y_picard, name="Picard Solution"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x_grid, y=y_exact, name="Exact Solution"))

fig.show()

fig.write_html("picard_vs_exact.html")
```

But when I try to run it, I get `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` error, can someone help me?

I want a graph to be shown.

Comment: The code you provided throws another error `NameError: name 'y_set' is not defined`. If you can provide the code that throws the `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` error so we can investigate further

Comment: Because you didn't assign `x`, could you recheck your code? What is `x` have to be?

Comment: @Constantin Hong
x is used as a variable in each function y in y_set
If I print out y, it comes out well as an expression for x, so I can't understand what the problem is

Comment: @DonPre
oh i'm sorry. I changed the code right now

Comment: Okay. Who produce `x`? I see no one produced it in your code. Is `x` produced from the enumerate function?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to pass a string in the `y.evalf(subs={'x': x_i})` part of your code.

Comment: Wow, I made the graph. How did you know that?

Comment: The `subs` argument substitute the expression with the value, so in this case you need to substitute the "x" not a variable called x. If you need more details check [this out](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/basic_operations.html)

Comment: What you are saying is, x in subs is not the x from math sign(the library uses) but indicate the lambda's s. So It should be a string. Is it correct?

Comment: @ConstantinHong exactly